# Can't make bootstrap work in Ember-cli

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I'm trying to import bootstrap into my ember-cli project, i followed the steps into the Usage section of [this page](https://github.com/linstula/ember-cli-bootstrap)

When I run the server I get these 2 errors:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot call `compile` without the template compiler loaded. Please load `ember-template-compiler.js` prior to calling `compile

Uncaught Error: Could not find module `ember-cli-bootstrap/utils/test-breadcrumbs` imported from `frontend/helpers/test-breadcrumbs`
```

I'm working with these versions:

ember: 0.2.7, 
node: 0.12.3, 
npm: 2.11.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always install bootstrap via bower

`bower install bootstrap --save`

then in your `Brocfile.js` add

`app.import('bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css');`

http://www.ember-cli.com/user-guide/#stylesheets

Comment: Don't forget to also import the JavaScript.

Comment: From Ember 2.0 onwards, they're using `ember-cli-build.js` instead of `Brocfile.js`. See https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/blob/master/TRANSITION.md

Answer (score 2):

I've been using ember-bootstrap http://kaliber5.github.io/ember-bootstrap/ with no issues. The older ember-cli-bootstrap project is clearly deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

Instructions for Ember 2.0+:

## 1. Install Bootstrap

Using Bower, simply run `bower install bootstrap --save`

## 2. Import Bootstrap in your Ember Application

Edit `ember-cli-build.js` and add:

```
app.import(app.bowerDirectory + '/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js');
app.import(app.bowerDirectory + '/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css');
```

## 3. Import Bootstrap in your HTML

If you created your project using ember-cli, it's not necessary. The `bootstrap.js` will be added to the `app.js` and the `bootstrap.js` will be added to the `vendor.css, both linked by default.